# How to make a call to Bitconverter.Getbytes generic?

Tags: generics, f#, inline, type-inference

```
let inline set (x: ^t) = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(x),0)
```

I've tried something like the above, but it does not work. Neither do type constraints or runtime resolved types. Also, I am guessing the answer is no, but would it be possible to tell the compiler that the generic type is simply float32 or float? It would save me a lot of bother.

Edit:

I am surprised that what Tomas Petricek wrote works while the reverse does not:

```
let inline toUint32 conv x = 
  let bytes = conv x
  BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0)

toUint32 BitConverter.GetBytes 9999.99f 
toUint32 BitConverter.GetBytes 9999.99
```

This is interesting. And neither can I make it work without the `conv : BitConvertible` in the other post.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to make a call to a bigger function generic. Though I think I've figure that out. I do not really need 'generic' per se, I just need it to accept float32 or float. `let inline sgeam2 transa transb (alpha: 't) (A:dMatrix<'t>) (beta: 't) (B:dMatrix<'t>) (C:dMatrix<'t>) =` This does not work. Instead what I just figured out that I could do is type alliasing. `type floatType = float32` and then `let inline sgeam2 transa transb (alpha: floatType) (A:dMatrix) (beta: floatType) (B:dMatrix) (C:dMatrix) =` Of course, inside the dMatrix class the float types are all floatType.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Edit your question instead of putting code in the comments. Also, what relationship to the OP do these comment signatures have?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Basically, like the cuBLAS sgeam that I am accessing from ManagedCuda, The above BitConverter.GetBytes() function has overloads for various types, but I can't figure out how to just write something to the effect `let inline RawConvertUInt32 x = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(x),0)` It is a F# type inference question pure and simple.

Comment: [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus) has generic functions like that, for instance ``ofBytes`` does what you want, with every numeric type.

Answer (score 3):

Static member constraints do not directly let you write inline functions that would call overloaded methods. The compiler cannot decide whether to type-check the function as if the argument was `float` or `float32` or any of the other supported types.

The simple solution is to pass the conversion function as a separate parameter:

```
let inline toUint32 x conv = 
  let bytes = conv x
  BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0)

toUint32 9999.99f BitConverter.GetBytes 
toUint32 9999.99 BitConverter.GetBytes
```

This requires a bit more typing, but it is quite easy to see what's going on. The caller just needs to provide a function that does the conversion - which can be, in typical cases, just `BitConverter.GetBytes`.

The other approach (already discussed in the other answer) is to use a slightly hacky trick that lets you specify more fancy static constraints; this removes the need for passing explicit functions and as long as it is hidden from the end user, it can make your code shorter.

Answer (score 2):

If you're prepared to do something a little bit unusual, you can generalise the function using statically resolved type constraints.

Be aware that this will not work from other .NET languages - statically resolved type constraints are entirely a feature of the F# compiler.

```
type BitConvertible = 
    |BitConvertible
    static member Convert (conv : BitConvertible, flt : float) =
        System.BitConverter.GetBytes(flt)
    static member Convert (conv : BitConvertible, flt32 : float32) =
        System.BitConverter.GetBytes(flt32)

module BitConverter =
    let inline convertToBytes x  =
        ((^T or ^U) : (static member Convert : ^T * ^U -> byte[]) (BitConvertible, x))
```

Then you can use it...

```
let a = BitConverter.convertToBytes 16.0
let b = BitConverter.convertToBytes 27.0f
```

Comment: What does `conv : BitConvertible` do? Is that there purely for type inference? I can't seem to make it work without it.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Yes, it would be easier if you could define static members on `float` or `float32` but you can't do that because they're built in types and extension methods aren't checked for the purposes of statically resolved type constraints.  Instead you define the functions on some other (totally arbitrary) type, in this case `BitConvertible`.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic By accepting/supplying a `BitConvertible` you provide a way of localising the `Convert` function to a particular type.  The syntax for defining functions in this way is notably horrible.  It's a tool you should definitely avoid when possible though I think legitimate uses do exist - I am using them to define host-device array conversions in a GPU library I am developing, for example.